# A question about sigma function

Tags: number-theory

If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\sigma(m).\sigma(n)=\sigma(m.n)$. I wrote $m$ and $n$ as their prime products but i still couldn't solve..

Can you help me with showing this?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sigma_Function_is_Multiplicative

Comment: I saw this but i still couldn't prove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to prove this using the well established methods of multiplicative functions but here is another, more direct approach.

If $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then share different prime sets. $m = \prod_i p_i^{a_i}, n = \prod_i q_i^{b_i}$.

Then $\sigma(m) = \prod_i(1+p_1+ \cdots + p_i^{a_i}), \sigma(n) = \prod_i(1+q_i+ \cdots+ q_i^{b_i})$.

Since $p_i$ and $q_i$ are distinct, $\sigma(mn) = \prod_i(1+p_1+ \cdots + p_i^{a_i})(1+q_i+ \cdots+ q_i^{b_i})$.

Comment: And $\sigma(n)$ is not stronly multiplicative, i.e., we really need the assumtion $gcd(n,m)=1$.